# Any way to simplify my code? Left joining multiple select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I figured out a way to combine 6 different select statements into one very long row which I can use my select statement to filter data out of. It works just like I need it to, however I feel like I have a ton of redundant code. Is there any way to simplify my code without changing the functionality at all?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT row1 FROM db1 
JOIN db2 ON ...
JOIN db3 ON ...
WHERE ...) t1

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT value_to_join FROM db4 v1, db1
JOIN db2 ON ...
JOIN db3 ON ...
WHERE ...) t2
ON t1.other_value = t2.other_value

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT value_to_join FROM db4 v2, db1
JOIN db2 ON ...
JOIN db3 ON ...
WHERE ...) t3
ON t1.other_value = t3.other_value
```

My output is a row from the first select statement joined with 5 different values from db4. These 5 values can only be joined with db1 when I join the other tables (db2, db3) because there is no common column to join on.

Some more information: This format of `left join` is used up to `t6`, with the ON being `t1.value = tn.value` with n increasing respectively. The join statements in each subquery are the same in all 6, so I'm assuming there has to be a way to simplify that. The '...' is just a mess of code that comes after each clause.

Comment: It is good to reduce the code to the core problem. But you reduced it too much. Hard to tell what you need here. Example data would probably help.

Comment: @juergend added a little more, and the only thing I really need is a way to reformat what I have to make it easier to read/edit because what I have now is just repetitive blocks of code with minor changes

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and the expected result? This is weird enough that odds are you don't have to do it, but from what you've provided it's difficult to tell what the overall goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports *not-so-old* SQL versions, (SQL 3 / SQL:1999), you may use CTE to achieve this:

```
WITH myquery (value,…) AS (
  SELECT * FROM db4, db1
  JOIN db2 ON ...
  JOIN db3 ON ...
  WHERE ...)

SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM db1 
  JOIN db2 ON ...
  JOIN db3 ON ...
  WHERE ...) t1

LEFT JOIN myquery t2
ON t1.value = t2.value

LEFT JOIN myquery t3
ON t1.value = t3.value

…
```

However, you will need to replace "`value,…`" and "SELECT `*`" in the first query by the exact list of wished columns.